# ESLint in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, eslint

Has anybody encountered the problem ESLint not loading in WebStorm? I'm trying to specify a path `/usr/local/bin/eslint`, `/usr/local/bin`,

Every time I got this message:

[image: Screenshot of the shown error message "Please specify ESLint package correctly"]

or `no such directory` message.

Comment: [Github  issues](https://github.com/idok/eslint-plugin/issues/22) doesnt help me

Comment: must be smth like '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint' - did you try this path?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to point that field to the actual ESLint script. This would usually be the place where you've installed the ESLint npm package or command-line tool.

[image: ESLint Package Location]

Comment: In my case, this doesn't work. I had to upgrade node to latest version which fixed the issue.

Comment: For me in Ruby Mine (also by JetBrains, same software company), the settings [look different and do not seem to apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NThs.png)

Comment: @sb813322 pasting outside URLs to images is not recommended, while such URLs usually expire after some time. Also your answer is offtopic while this question clearly talks about WebStorm and not other product(s).

Comment: @Lukas Thanks for the info. I didn't post an answer, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 12):

OS X El Capitan

I've installed npm & node with brew. It's easy to keep stuff up to date with brew.

1. `brew install node`

then installed eslint globally with npm

2. `npm i eslint -g`

and here is my working config:

3. `/usr/local/bin/node` `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint`

I add .eslintrc file with eslint rules in project's root folder.

Try using those drop-downs next to input field, webstorm gives path w/o any typing.

[image]

Comment: Installing node via homebrew also fixed a permission error that I was having install global packages. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind, that when you want to lint in CI / CD , the eslint versions might differ and thus create errors u don't have on local machines ...

Comment: That's true, yet i had no issues with that yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... please consider [the comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808857/eslint-in-webstorm#comment132135181_31196230), which also applies to this answer.

Answer (score 9):

Following are the steps you need to get it working  on **Windows 10**:

1. Open command prompt and navigate to your project root.
2. Run the following command:
   `npm install eslint --save-dev`
3. Once ESLint finishes installing in the above step, navigate through the following menus in Webstorm:
   `File > Settings...`. Click on **Settings...**
4. In the Settings screen that shows up, in the top-left hand corner, there is a Search box. Type `eslint` in it.
5. That will show you the 'ESLint' settings for this project. Now tick the checkbox that says "Enable". Make sure that the **Node interpreter:** has the right value. In my case, it was `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`
6. Just below the **Node interpreter:** setting, there is a setting called **ESLint package:**. If you have correctly installed  the ESLint package as I mentioned in Step 2 above, this setting will be auto-populated to show the current path of ESLint package from your project's `node_modules` folder. In my case, the value of this setting was:
   `D:\www\gdp\node_modules\eslint`  ***(gdp is my project root folder)***
7. Click on **Apply** and **OK** buttons respectively.
8. Restart Webstorm. If you have successfully completed all the steps, you will not see the prompt to enter the ESLint again.
9. Enjoy!!!

Comment: `npm install eslint --save-dev` unfortunately gives me `npm ERR! must provide string spec`, `npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`, `npm ERR!     /home/sb813322/.npm/_logs/2022-12-21T09_41_45_009Z-debug-0.log`

Comment: I suggest you to try the solutions mentioned here and see if that fixes the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645510/npm-install-gets-the-error-must-provide-string-spec

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue and I installed the ES Lint again through the command,
npm install --save-dev eslint

I had settings to automatic but still the popup was there, so I restarted the IDE, and the popup was gone.