# npm install gets the error "must provide string spec"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I try to execute an old react app which is created by myself two years ago. When I try to run the app via "npm install", I've got the following error:

```
npm ERR! must provide string spec
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tws80\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-09T21_00_13_180Z-debug.log
```

The dependencies of my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.7",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@mdi/js": "^5.0.45",
    "@mdi/react": "^1.3.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "i18next": "^19.3.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.8",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2", 
    "react-html-email": "^3.0.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.3.3",
    "react-intl": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

My current node and npm version:

```
node -v v16.13.1
npm -v 8.1.2
```

I suppose this error is due to the old dependencies but I don't find any useful workaround to solve this problem. After I've removed node_modules I still can re-install node_modules.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What version of NPM?  Can you post your package.json?

Comment: @Joe, thank you! You can see my npm version and pyckage.json above

Comment: do you have any other sections in your package.json?  perhaps an `engines` section or possibly an old comments section (`"//": {}`) that is no longer allowed?

Comment: @Joe, In my package.json there is no engines section but in package-lock.json does. On the other hand, there exist no old comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I created a new react app and then copy & pasted the `package.json` from the new app into the old app, the command `npm install` did work.

Answer (score 32):

Running `rm -rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm i` in a **bash** terminal fixed it for me.

Running `npm -v` yields --> `8.3.0` on my local machine

Comment: npm -i doesn't work for me at all. My npm is 8.1.2, should I upgrade?

Comment: scrub the p.lock and node modules first using the bash command above; then try again

Comment: this solution didn't work for me. I am using `node v14.20.0` and `npm 8.18.0` on Ubuntu `20.04.4 LTS`.

Comment: you could consider changing the two `rm` to `\rm` to make sure no aliases etc. get in the way. In my case, trash-cli did.

Answer (score 12):

Not need to create new packages.
Removing `package-lock.json` and running `npm install` I resolved my problem.

Comment: This file contains the information of all installed packages. There's no sensible reason to delete this.

Comment: It will automatically create package-lock.json when you run "npm install". So, don't bother.

Comment: I must've been tired when I read your answer because I thought you were talking about package.json. My bad...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you put some package options into the "dependencies" part of your package.json. I had the same bug with autoprefixer browserlist options. Remove `"editor.formatOnPaste": true` and `"editor.formatOnSave": true` and the npm install will work as expected - I did check it locally. My guess is that under "dependencies" or "devDependencies" only packages' versions are expected.

Answer (score 3):

Your npm package has to be initialized first:
`npm init`
Afterwards you should bee able to execute your commands.

Comment: If this is meant to be an answer according to [answer] it needs some [edit]ing to make that more obvious. Currently is reads like a debugging proposal without explanation, which should be in a comment - and explained.  (Though you probably are aware of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead )

Comment: I just got the same problem solved with that and wanted to share quick

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your package-lock.json has something wrong. You could remove this file and run a fresh `npm install` which will re-generate a new one for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```bash
npm upgrade
```

Then

```bash
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of *package-lock.json*. Just Removing *package-lock.json* and running *npm install --force* resolved my problem.

Comment: In my case, it's due lockfileVersion been change to 3

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped: `npm upgrade --legacy-peer-deps` or `npm upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had accidentally started putting a reference into "package.json", then got distracted and forgot to fill it in.

I ended up with something dumb like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": null,
```

Removing the null line fixed it. Dumb, but maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you have merge conflicts in a `package-lock.json` file they are automatically resolved by running `npm install`. However, if one of the merge conflicts happens at the top of your lock file:

```json
  "name": "my-package",
<<<<<<< HEAD
  "version": "0.22.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
=======
  "version": "0.21.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
>>>>>>> 030a02e (chore(deps): upgrade packages)
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
```

Then npm is unable to resolve those and will throw:

```
must provide string spec
```

Resolving the top conflict in `package-lock.json` manually and then running `npm install` to resolve the remaining conflicts will resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

run
`sudo npm i -g npm-check-updates`

then
`sudo npm init`

then do a comparison of the two `package.json` files
pull old code into new json file.

then
`sudo npm install`

that should do the trick, I think

Comment: You should very, very rarely, be running a sudo npm install.

Comment: @Dwight On my linux machine every thing that has to do with global I need to run sudo

Comment: installing npm globally, sure, npm init and npm install are local tools that should nearly all of the time only be used for local, non-privileged installs. The reason you need to run sudo npm i is because you're running sudo npm init, which creates root permissioned files that are actually running in regular user space - you're forcing your _entire_ application to be run as root, which isn't only dangerous, but also just inconvenient. I actually don't remember that even installing npm globally should _require_ root privs - you should be able to install in via something like /usr/local.