# I want to do a project with react and I have to use ez-react-table but I cannot install it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

npm ERR! must provide string spec

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-18T17_54_22_923Z-debug.log.Program gives me an error with this type.

Comment: Have you tried searching for your log messages? Try this one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645510/npm-install-gets-the-error-must-provide-string-spec

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happen, first delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file , then run npm install again